# Docebo oAuth2 JWT bearer- Public key invalid?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, rsa, public-key-encryption, bearer-token

Currently, I am integrating docebo API with python rest client. While creating an oAuth2 application in docebo with JWT bearer grant permission they are asking to upload the public key.

I have generated public key using below command on mac
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C <user id>`

As they have mentioned public key format should be

```
—–BEGIN PUBLIC KEY—–

MIGeMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GMADCBiAKBgGOrtjv/oPcaWIQL7h3DwvGbWFhH
fAIP02pPPw1Cp8h0SUkmGAWUGKCNH2WuIeNxPlRZKmW86aivknrRtEN3QW6eEsFZ
ZSIKVmUPekKrSpvYmYwkTCnwCb4gpDu1ZPEde8VXhQjLRl7ielUktzzbXW7v1HmI
fDASHvMvIl4kwGA/AgMBAAE=

—–END PUBLIC KEY—–
```

According to that, I have converted `id_rsa.pub` to `publicKey.pem` using below command

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -m 'PEM' -e > publicKey.pem
chmod 600 public.pem
```

Still, I am not able to upload the publicKey.pem on the oauth2 application. Error is `Public key is invalid`.

Any idea about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer. Hopefully it can help others.

We use open ssl (https://www.openssl.org/source/) solved this issue. Run the commands below and import rsa_public.pem into Docebo.

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rsa_private.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem
```